# Ubuntu sftp chroot jail on usb folder

Tags: ubuntu, sftp

I have a problem configuring the sftp chroot jail on ubuntu on a folder that is stored on a usb.
I have a Toshiba 4tb external hard disk, that it's automounted via `fstab` on `/sftp` path.

```
UUID={UUID} /sftp ext4 auto,defaults,nofail,rw 0 0
```

I have followed all the necessary steps to configure the sftp jail

```
sudo groupadd sftponly

sudo useradd -g sftponly -s /bin/false -m -d /sftp/backupsftp backupsftp

sudo passwd backupsftp

sudo chown root: /sftp/backupsftp

sudo chmod 755 /sftp/backupsftp

sudo mkdir /sftp/backupsftp/backup

sudo chmod 755 /sftp/backupsftp/backup

sudo chown backupsftp:sftponly /sftp/backupsftp/backup
```

Then added to the bottom of the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file

```
Match Group sftponly
  ChrootDirectory %h
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
Match all
```

And setted the following value (always in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file):

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Port 22
AddressFamily inet
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
```

Finally I have restarted the services:

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

When I try to connect with WinScp I get this error:
[image: screenshot error]

`Linux syslogs`:

```
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of backupsftp.
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1005...
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[1]: Started Session 1350 of user backupsftp.
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[13303]: gpgconf: running /usr/bin/gpg-agent failed (exitcode=2): General error
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[13303]: gpgconf: fatal error (exit status 1)
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[13303]: Reached target Timers.
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[13303]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[13303]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[13303]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[13303]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[13303]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[13303]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[13303]: Reached target Sockets.
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[13303]: Reached target Paths.
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[13303]: Reached target Basic System.
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[13303]: Reached target Default.
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[13303]: Startup finished in 42ms.
Jun 24 14:46:53 bbserver systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1005.
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1005...
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[13303]: Stopped target Default.
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[13303]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[13303]: Stopped target Timers.
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[13303]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[13303]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[13303]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[13303]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[13303]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[13303]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[13303]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[13303]: Stopped target Paths.
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[13303]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[13303]: Starting Exit the Session...
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[13303]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 13381 (kill).
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1005.
Jun 24 14:46:54 bbserver systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of backupsftp.
```

Everything **works correctly** if the **home directory** of the user created resides on the main disk and not on the usb

**UPDATE:**

`/sftp` folder permssion:

`drwxrwxr-x   4 root root       4096 Jun 30 14:15 sftp/`

`sshd logs:`

```
Jun 30 14:25:24 bbserver sshd[2429]: Accepted password for backupsftp from 192.168.0.62 port 65380 ssh2
Jun 30 14:25:24 bbserver sshd[2429]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user backupsftp by (uid=0)
Jun 30 14:25:24 bbserver systemd-logind[1106]: New session 76758 of user backupsftp.
Jun 30 14:25:24 bbserver systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user backupsftp by (uid=0)
Jun 30 14:25:25 bbserver sshd[2559]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/sftp/"
Jun 30 14:25:25 bbserver sshd[2429]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user backupsftp
Jun 30 14:25:25 bbserver systemd-logind[1106]: Removed session 76758.
```

Comment: What are the permissions and ownership for the `/sftp` directory? And are there any syslogs from sshd?

Comment: I have updated my question, as you thought it is a permissions problem on the /sftp folder